# SQL Server database - best way to deal with mass amounts of data

Tags: sql-server, database, large-data

I have a SQL Server database and I'm looking for a design to store mass amounts of data.

I'm running various throughput tests on different software builds and for each level of attenuation I'm obtaining metrics. There are 50 levels of attenuation for each software build for each device and multiple devices will be tested.

I also want to display graphs for each build on each device.

I'm currently thinking of storing to xml file and reading off that.

Thanks.

EDIT: I suppose my specific question is can SQL Server handle the amount of data I'm feeding it?

EDIT2: I'm displaying data results for other tests internally using graphs, so that really isn't an issue. The issue is can SQL Server handle that amount of data and if not what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: I'd say a table is the way to go. And don't store XML in your table, please.

Comment: XML isn't a storage format. It's far too bloated for that, and the load/parse overhead is insane. It's a data transmission format more than anything.

Comment: SQL databases are designed to handle large amounts of data... what makes you assume that SQL Server wouldn't be able to handle your amount of data?  Also, can you quantify how much data are you expecting?  Millions of records? Billions of records?

Comment: Well, 50 data points * 4 tests * 1-2 builds per day * 8 devices continuously

Comment: Facebook uses MySQL, which is comparable to SQL Server. Facebook probably records billions of menial status messages per day. It still functions, and its servers aren't magic. SQL can handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SQL Server can absolutely handle that amount of data, and it can be pretty speedy about it, too. That's precisely what database engines are built for.

And XML is much, much, much slower than a database, which is why nobody uses it for high-end data storage.

Answer (score 0):

May be SQL Server is not the right solution for you at all.

If you need a graph representation of your data stored with persistence you can try to see if a nosql solution is better for your own case. Check out orientdb (Java document/graph DB). You could also check http://www.nuvolabase.com/ where you can use orientdb in cloud for free.

HTH

Comment: I believe he is referring to graph as an image, chart, or diagram... not graph as a data structure.